# Trigger event for specific plugin only

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin, plugin-events

Is it possible to trigger a event for specific plugin?

I can load a specific plugin

`$loaded = JPluginHelper::importPlugin('my_component', 'my_plugin_1');`

But when I trigger an event, all the plugins that have that event are fired:

`$results = JEventDispatcher::getInstance()->trigger('my_event');`

I get the results not only of plugin1 but all the plugins that listen to that event.

`$results = ['my_plugin_1_response', 'my_plugin_2_response']`;

Is it possible to limit the plugins listening to the event to `my_plugin_1_response` only?

Please note that one possible solution would be to order the plugins and get the `$results[0]` as the result, but I'm not interested in this, I don't want that the other plugins are fired at all.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, an event dispatcher does not support this concept.  You're better off directly calling that single function versus going through a dispatcher if you really only want one response from one location.

Joomla 4.0 will use the refactored [Event package](https://github.com/joomla-framework/event/tree/2.0-dev) as its base for event management, and the EventInterface contains a `stopPropagation()` method which a listener (your plugins) can call which will instruct the event dispatcher to stop propagating the event to additional listeners.  So you have that to look forward to.

Comment: Thank you Michael for the info! The problem calling that function directly is that it won't be able to access params through $this->params, so I would need a workaround. Probably the best solution -in my case- will be to prefix the method so the plugins don't share the same event name. I will have to wait for Joomla 4 then! 

Comment: ```
$plugin = JPluginHelper::getPlugin($type, $pluginName);
$params = new Registry($plugin->params);
```

As long as you aren't dynamically setting params in the plugin, that'll give you what's in the database.